# PyQt5 -- show dialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, showdialog

[image]

First, you have to close the existing window otherwise it will not allow an opening new window or close the entire program. How can I do this in the Python library PyQt5.

Comment: Use one of the [static functions of QMessageBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#static-public-members), or QDialog if you need more advanced controls.

Answer (score 0):

To show a dialog in PyQt, you can use

```
error_dialog = QMessageBox()
error_dialog.setWindowTitle("Your title")
error_dialog.setText("Your message")
error_dialog.exec()
```

Comment: What has pubsub to do with the question?

Comment: @musicamante yeah you're right, it has nothing to do with the question...I misread the question, now I fixed my answer